# Multi-sheet printing of large-scale maps

Tags: qgis

Mapping a specific region at a larger scale, this region does not fit onto a single sheet of paper. For example mapping Austria at 1: 1 mio needs three sheets of din A4 paper.
Question: Can I do multi-sheet printing of large-scale maps in QGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not trying the [Atlas composer tool](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html)? Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Could you please give a few more hints?

Comment: The principle is to create a grid as a new shapefile and then activate the 'Atlas' option in the QGIS composer. There are multiple demos online. I am natively french speaking so I don't know about a good tutorial in english. You can check [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7zuztxjExE), which is in french but easy to follow.

Comment: well, its easy to follow, when you speak French ;-) (which unfortunately I dont) and you have a good magnifying glass (I am visually impaired). But your hint gave the right direction, so thank you very much - for a textual step by step in English see the link I poste below:

Comment: Welldone for the english link and glad that it revealed to be better for both sound ...and image :-) !

Answer (score 1):

Ok , I found a detail step by step here:
http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/de/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html, starting at 14.6.6: Follow Along: Creating an Atlas Coverage